# What is the difference between down_read(), down_read_nested(), and down_read_non_owner()

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, semaphore

What is the difference between `down_read()`, `down_read_nested()`, and `down_read_non_owner()` in the Linux kernel?

I tried to search on the internet, but I could not find a good description besides confused conversations. The source code itself, does not have proper comments.

My question is related to the rw_semaphore in the Linux kernel. Here is a link to the file that has all these functions: http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v2.6.38.8/source/kernel/rwsem.c

Specific questions I have:

- Is the nested version related to allowing a thread to down read the semaphore more than once? Well, there is no need for that. A thread can do that already with the plain down read version, as long as it is up read the same number of times.
  What is its intended use? And how is it different from the plain version?
- What does the non-owner version even mean? As far as I know, a read lock does not mean the semaphore is owned by the locking process. It simply prevents write locks. A thread intending to `down_write` the semaphore has to wait for all down readers. So, does non-owner mean a down writes are allowed? Well, then this not safe. And this defeats the whole purpose of having a semaphore.

Comment: Maybe you should point to the source (add a URL).  It might be good to specify "functions used in the Linux kernel" (or something similar) before the question mark; it clarifies context quickly that _is_ available from the tags but should really be in the question proper.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for the tip. I will update the question.

Comment: Did you find/look at https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SyncPrim/sync-5.html?  What about http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-5-sect-3?  That seems less helpful.

Comment: Yes, I have read some of those long time ago. But none of these answer any of my questions. I am asking specifically the "non_owner" and "nested" parts.